# Why should we Class Modeling?

Tags: class, uml, modeling, class-diagram

why should we use modeling?
I currently write classes in my projects without having a model.
I think about the tasks of each class and write methods.
Now I want to know what makes modeling better? !
And how to use it? !
I'm familiar with UML design
Thanks .

Comment: @jdv this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @cooder, "I'm familiar with UML design Thanks ." so just tell us: the models you already did, did they help you or not ? And you get your answer ...

Comment: @gnat, the comment said something like "you can do some research over there, and see if an eventual comment is more appropriate there". It was hardly a strong recommendation. Given the first two bullet points on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I think this was perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

**Modeling classes has the following benefits:**

- Modeling allows you to design faster a complex software structure that requires the involvement of several classes:

  - On the model, you draw a couple of classes and links between them (associations, dependencies, etc...).  You can then verify the consequences and fine tune the model.
  - While you could easily create a code skeleton to show several classes and perhaps some inheritance, it's more difficult to represent associations in code:  is it a composition ? an aggregation ? a one to many ? or a many-to-many ?  Each of this alternative would require some choices about how to implement the link, and this takes much more time.  ANd once these choices are made and and the draft code will be done, you'll be less encline to change it.
- Modeling allows a more compact overview over a complex class structure:

  - You can easily show 20 classes (without details) on a sheet of paper, and grasp how the parts are connected together.
  - With an IDE you can perhaps show 20  classes on a screen  by folding the classes,  but if you need to see the relation between the classes (so some details about class members, you dramatically decrease what you can show (and grasp) at once.
- Modeling allows interactive discussions with people of diverse backgrounds, and not necessarily coding gurus. While business users won't grasp the subtle details of a model, they can grasp the relations and so participate constructively to the discussions.
- Modeling provides a useful documentation for people who will join the project or will have to maintain it.

**Modelling is not a substitute for programming**

I wouldn't like to start a heated dogmatic debate.  But I think that modeling should not replace programming:

- If you start to put all the details on all the members of all the classes  in your model, and then start to express complex constraints in OCL,  you loose could loose your time, except if you work on mission critical systems in highly regulated environments.
- The model will quickly be out of sync with the code, because in most of the case, only few projects have so much resources that they could afford double maintenance.

If you have some advanced tooling (e.g. Rational Rose for OOP or S-Designer for database models) that can do modeling, code generation, reverse engineering to update model and so on,  then it can make sense to put much more effort in the model.

If not,  design the outline of your system in a model without too much details (e.g.put members important for the understanding of the overall structure and responsibilities), and keep the additional effort for the coding.

Comment: Thanks for Description .